# Не работает копирование в буфер обмена

Tags: javascript, clipboard

Есть функция:

```
const copyToClipboard = function (text) {
if (!navigator.clipboard) {
  const $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val(text).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
} else {
  navigator.clipboard
    .writeText(text)
    .then(() => {})
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error in copying text: ", err);
    });
}
```

};

В файрфокс (последняя версия) перестали работать оба варианта. Не могу найти решение. Помогите

Comment: Для работы с буфером обмена необходимо чтобы пользователь повзаимодействовал со страницей

Comment: так функция и вызывается как раз на его взаимодействие со страницей

Comment: Необходим `HTTPS` защищенный протокол для работы копирования, допускается копирование с `localhost`, в иных случаях копирование не будет работать. Более подробно описано здесь: [This feature is available only in secure contexts HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write)